# Check if a type exists as a property of another type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have some types:

```
interface IMyParentInterface {
    foo: string,
    items: IMyChildinterface[]
}

interface IMyChildinterface {
   id: number,
   bar: string,
}
```

And I have a class which uses the interfaces:

```
class MyClass<T, D = keyof T> {...}
```

So, I'm creating the instance:

```
const class = new MyClass<IMyParentInterface, IMyChildinterface>(...)
```

So I want to strictly check if `IMyChildinterface` is that exact type, that is used as a `IMyParentInterface` property.

In other words, I **shouldn't be able** to do something like this:

```
const class = new MyClass<IMyParentInterface, TJustRandomType>(...)
```

Unfortunatelly, `typeof` does nothing to make it work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to restrict types to specific subsets by `extends` keyword. Consider:

```
class MyClass<
T extends { items: any }, 
D extends T['items'][number] = T['items'][number]> { };

const a = new MyClass<IMyParentInterface, IMyChildinterface>(); //ok

interface Other {
    a: string
}
const b = new MyClass<IMyParentInterface, Other>(); //error
```

Explanation:

- `T extends { items: any }` as you put there generic, I assume `IMyParentInterface` is not one and only type you want to use. I am then restricting that our first type has `items` property
- `D extends T['items'][number] = T['items'][number]` - restriction that second type will be the type from the first `items` property item type.
- Take a look that now putting the second type is not nesesery as it will be by default what you want

---

#### More generic solution with picking the wanted key:

```
// proposition with picking the property
class MyClass<
Prop extends PropertyKey, 
T extends Record<Prop, any>, 
D extends T[Prop][number] = T[Prop][number]> { }
const a = new MyClass<'items', IMyParentInterface, IMyChildinterface>(); //ok

interface Other {
    a: string
}
const b = new MyClass<'items', IMyParentInterface, Other>(); //error
```

#### Even more generic with inferring type of array kind properties

```
// proposition with every array type property
type PickByValue<T, V, _Keys extends keyof T = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends V ? K : never
}[keyof T]> = Pick<T, _Keys>

class MyClass<
    T extends (Array<any> extends T[keyof T] ? object : never),
    D extends _E[keyof _E][number],
    _E extends Record<any, Array<any>> = PickByValue<T, Array<any>>
    > { }
const a = new MyClass<IMyParentInterface, IMyChildinterface>(); //ok

interface Other {
    a: string
}
const b = new MyClass<IMyParentInterface, Other>(); //error
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I can't hard code things like `items` or `number`. It's just for demonstration purposes. This class is supposed to be pretty flexible to accept any interfaces, The main thing is the second interface must be a property of the first interface.

Comment: Any property or you want to choose, because if any you will get union type of all properties types. Any requirement about the property? In this example it is array kind. Please tell me more and we will figurate out :)

Comment: Your latest update is the best solution! Thanks a lot. If only I could understand what's going on there... :)